# stylesheet reference issue

Tags: html, css

I have a stylesheet defined in the index.html as

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/template.css">
```

Inside the template.css, I have declared

```
body{
background-image: url(images/background.png);
background-repeat: repeat;
}
```

Why is the image not getting displayed? The path is correct

Comment: Can you tell us the directory structure in your web server? Have you checked the permissions so the web server have access to the images directory?

Answer (score 5):

The path in the CSS should be relative to where the CSS file is located, not from where the  page where the CSS file is being loaded from.

Try:

```
background-image: url(../images/background.png);
```

When you are starting out, this can seem counter intuitive, but it's actually a good design as your CSS file can then be called from any page in any folder and the references to the images will not be broken.

Comment: Second that.  I had this same issue the other day.  Same fix, too.